# I get "syntax error near unexpected token `done' " when I use while loop in bash

Tags: bash, file, while-loop

I have a file which filled in streaming way line by line. I need to decrease the volume of the file by deleting the oldest record in it. 
I would like to count the number of lines and if the number of lines exceed than 100 then delete the oldest lines. However I got the following error:

```
./1.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./1.sh: line 18: `done'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="11.txt"
linenum=0

while true; do

#Count number of lines
linenum=`cat "$FILE" | wc -l`

while [ $linenum -gt 100 ] do

#Delete the head of file (oldest)
sed -i 1,1d "$FILE"

#Count number of lines
linenum=`cat "$FILE" | wc -l`

done

done
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: This isn't safe. `sed -i` (effectively) makes a copy of the input file, then replaces the original with the modified copy. If the original is written to while `sed` is working on the copy, those changes are lost.

Comment: @chepner: thanks for mentioning this, do you have any idea?

Comment: Whatever is *writing* to the file needs to be responsible for trimming it.

Comment: @chepner: It does't work! when I applied it on a streaming file, it could't work! :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a linefeed or a `;` between the `while`'s condition and the `do` :

```
while [ $linenum -gt 100 ]; do

    #Delete the head of file (oldest)
    sed -i 1,1d "$FILE"

    #Count number of lines
    linenum=$(wc -l "$FILE")

done
```

I also indented the code properly, changed the subshell `` `...` `` notation to the more modern `$(...)` and removed a redundant use of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semicolon  at below line

```
while [ $linenum -gt 100 ] do
```

should be

```
while [ $linenum -gt 100 ] ; do
```

Hope this helps.